# How could I disable standard Top bar ( with battery,time info) in ios 6 app

Tags: ios

My question is: How could I disable standard Top bar ( with battery,time info) in ios 6 app ?

i mean exactly that one :

[image]

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that is the status bar. you can hide this by setting property "`Status Bar Initially hidden`." to "`YES`" in info.plist file

you can also hide by code,like this

```
 [ UIApplication application setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
```